# VB.Net 2003 - How to create DataGrid Button Column with Bound Column ability?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2003

I'm creating a DataGrid in VB.Net 2003 which gets data from SQL. All columns with SQL data are BoundColumn with an additional ButtonColumn at the end to change status of a column.

In this state I can click the button of a row and the corresponding data on that row can change without issue. But my problem comes when I have to add a filter function to the DataGrid.

Once the data has ben filtered, and I try to click on the button of the 1st row, I see no changes. It is only until I remove the filter and notice that the data changed on the 1st unfiltered row.

```
1. Before filter data:

001 | QW34 | OK | <BUTTON>
002 | XC00 | OK | <BUTTON>
003 | GH66 | OK | <BUTTON>

2. After filter data:

002 | XC00 | OK | <BUTTON>

3. Click the button to change OK to NG and vice versa.

4. Filter data remains the same. Return back to original table state.

001 | QW34 | NG | <BUTTON>
002 | XC00 | OK | <BUTTON>
003 | GH66 | OK | <BUTTON>
```

Hopefully this can help explain my point. Basically, since the button column is just a normal ButtonColumn, it is not bound to the rows of the BoundColumn, so whenever there is a change in the rows from the filter, the Button column remains the same.

How can I get my Button Column to have the same properties as Bound Column? Is there addiitoanl properties I'm not aware of in VB.Net 2003 that can do this?

Here is the sub to bind my SQL data into my DataGrid. Along with the sub to filter data.

```
Public Sub BindGrid()

    Dim strSql As String = "Select * from [SQL3].[dbo].[Final] order by [Course Code]"
    Dim dtb As New DataTable
    SQLDB.Open()
    Dim dad As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql, SQL)
    dad.Fill(dtb)
    SQL.Close()
    DataGrid1.DataSource = dtb
    DataGrid1.DataBind()
    dtb.Clear()

End Sub

Public Sub filter()

    If DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString = "[ALL]" Then

        Call BindGrid()

    Else

        Dim strSelectCmd As String = "Select * from [SQL3].[dbo].[Final] where result = '" & DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString & "'"
        Dim dtb As New DataTable
        SQL.Open()
        Dim dad As New SqlDataAdapter(strSelectCmd, SQL)
        dad.Fill(dtb)
        SQL.Close()
        DataGrid1.DataSource = dtb
        DataGrid1.DataBind()

    End If

End Sub
```

And here is the sub for button column in each row to change flag status and update to SQL.

```
Private Sub CellClick_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles DataGrid1.ItemCommand

    Session("Employee_No") = e.Item.Cells(2).Text
    Session("Course_Code") = e.Item.Cells(0).Text
    Session("Flag") = e.Item.Cells(8).Text

    'Change Flag Status in SQL
    If Session("Flag") = "Active" Then
        Dim updateState As String = "update [SQLDB3].[dbo].[ZOJT_EMP_COURSE]" _
                            & "set [Flag] = 'Inactive'" _
                            & "where Employee_No = '" & Session("Employee_No") & "'" _
                            & "and CourseCode = '" & Session("Course_Code") & "'"

        Dim conn = SQLDB
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(updateState, conn)

        conn.open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.close()

        Label3.Text = Session("Course_Code")

        Call filter()

        conn.dispose()
        command.Dispose()

        'Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(), True)

    ElseIf Session("Flag") = "Inactive" Then
        Dim updateState As String = "update [SQLDB3].[dbo].[ZOJT_EMP_COURSE]" _
                            & "set [Flag] = 'Active'" _
                            & "where Employee_No = '" & Session("Employee_No") & "'" _
                            & "and CourseCode = '" & Session("Course_Code") & "'"

        Dim conn = SQLDB
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(updateState, conn)


        conn.open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.close()

        Label3.Text = Session("Course_Code")

        Call filter()

        conn.dispose()
        command.Dispose()


    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: May I ask why you are still using VB.NET 2003 when VS Community 2017 is free? There would be some legitimate reasons but they're few and wouldn't apply to many people. For the record, the reason I ask is that a `DataGridView` would be much easier to work with than a `DataGrid`. VS 2017 can target right back to .NET 2.0 so you should be OK even if you need to develop for Windows XP.

Comment: Remote PC only has this version running. I would like to use newer versions. But work requires me to use this. I have no say in the matter unfortunately.

Comment: Please help... I'm so desperate to get this done today...

Comment: t's a long time since I have used a `DataGrid`. I'll help if I can but I don't have the time right now to create a new project and reacquaint myself with that control. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Then is it possible if I program my filter sub to remove the existing DataBind on my DataGrid, then re-insert a new DataBind with filtered search data into that DataGrid? Trying to think outside the box here and this is the 1st idea that comes to mind. Would that work?

Comment: How are you filtering the data? Like I said, I haven't used a `DataGrid` for a long time but I would think that you should be able to bind a `DataTable` and then set the `DefaultView.RowFilter` of that `DataTable` to filter the data displayed in the grid.

Comment: I use a DropDownList to select the value and then use a filter sub to get a different data set using SQL. I'll edit the question to include it.

Comment: I guess that it is also relevant how you're actually editing the data.  If the grid is bound then you should be making changes via the data source rather than the grid.  It may be that accessing the relevant `CurrencyManager` and calling `BeginEdit` first and then `EndEdit` would force the changes to be displayed immediately. You might also be able to call `Refresh` on the `CurrencyManager` to force the bound control(s) to be refreshed at any time. You should be able to access that `CurrencyManager` using something like `Me.BindingContext(myDataTable)` in the form.

Comment: You need to show all the relevant code. It sounds to me like you are making the changes to the wrong data. How much data is there in total? If it's not a lot then don't perform multiple queries. Just get all the data once and then filter locally. then you can't edit the wrong data.

Comment: Just posted the relevant code. As for the amount of data there is a Add New Entry form along with it to add new data into the table. So it'll grow once it goes live.

Comment: And where's the editing code? I suspect that the issue is that you're always making the changes to `dsgroup.Tables("list")` even if `dsgroup1.Tables("list1")` is what's bound to the grid. That would explain why you don't see the changes until you rebind the full table.

Comment: The amount that the data will grow is irrelevant because you are already retrieving all of it.  The first query gets the entire table worth of data so the second query is completely pointless. You've already got all the data that that query could possibly retrieve so why retrieve it again? Do as I said and just filter via the `DefaultView` of the one `DataTable`.

Comment: OK. Sorry for taking your time again. But for this situation my DropDownList for filter selection is a string combination of 2 columns of my SQL. The column exists in SQL but not in my DataTable. DataTable only has the 2 columns which are separate. In this case is it still posibble to use the DefaultView method. I hope you can make sense of what I said. Never really used DefaultView and it's getting late at my place, so I'm a little blurry...

Comment: Took me some time. But I finally changed my bind method to using data table as source.